# Is this basis for complex matrices necessarily a unitary basis?

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, trace, unitary-matrices, similar-matrices

Let us consider the vector space of complex $n \times n$ matrices.

Let $\{ V_i \}_{i=1,2,\cdots,n^2}$ be a trace-orthogonal basis of matrices, i.e.,
$$ \forall i,j \in \{1,2,\cdots,n^2\} : \quad \textrm{tr}(V_i^\dagger V_j) = n \; \delta_{ij}. $$

In general, such matrices do not need to be unitary (e.g., the [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) are a nice example for $n=3$). However, let us presume an additional condition: there exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that
$$ \forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n^2\}: \quad M V_i M^{-1} \textrm{is a unitary matrix}. $$
In particular, this implies that each $V_i$ (and in fact arbitrary products $V_{i_1} V_{i_2} \cdots V_{i_k}$) are *similar* to unitary matrices.

*Question: Do the above two properties imply that each $V_i$ is unitary?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the dagger symbol means conjugate transpose, then the answer is yes.

The fact that $M V_i M^{-1}$ is unitary means arbitrary $V_i$ has all eigenvalues on the unit circle.  And
$n=\textrm{trace}\big(V_i^\dagger V_i\big) =\big \Vert V_i\big\Vert_F^2 \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda_k^{(i)}\vert^2=\sum_{k=1}^n 1 =n$
$\implies$  each $V_i$ is normal since Schur's Inequality is met with equality.  Applying spectral theorem we have $V_i =Q_i D_i Q_i^{-1}=Q_i D_i Q_i^\dagger$ i.e. $V_i$ is the product of 3 unitary matrices hence it is unitary.

Comment: great, thank you! Do you know if the result remains true if M V_i M^{-1} is a unitary *up to a prefactor* ?

Comment: what does unitary "up to a pre-factor" mean?

Comment: I mean $ M V_i M^{-1} = a U_i$ for a unitary $U_i$ and a nonzero number $a \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Schur's Inequality implies $\vert a \vert \leq 1$ and if the inequality is strict then $V_i$ cannot be normal.

Comment: Right but I am presuming the value of $|a|$ is an unknown. Note that my above problem has a lot of structure (e.g. orthogonal basis etc), so perhaps using that extra structure one can prove that $|a|=1$? I am not sure.

Comment: I already have told you that $\vert a \vert =1$ is necesary for $V_i$ to be "unitary up to a prefactor"; and obviously $M V_i M^{-1} = a U_i$ for $\vert a \vert =1$ is still the original problem.

Comment: To avoid confusion, let me rephrase. I am wondering if the following (generalized) statement is true: "If (i) $\textrm{tr}(V_i^\dagger V_j) = n\delta_{ij}$ and (ii) there exists a positive number $a_i > 0$ and an invertible matrix $M$ such that $a_i M V_i M^{-1}$ is a unitary matrix; then $V_i$ is unitary". Per your argument, it would be sufficient to prove $|a_i|=1$, since the unitarity follows from Schur's inequality. I am not sure whether this is provable, or whether a counter-example exists.

Comment: I have already answered this, though you have changed from $M V_i M^{-1} = a U_i$ to $a_i M V_i M^{-1} = U_i$ for some reason.  You responded to my comment about Schur's Inequality implications less than 3 minutes after I posted it leading me to think you did not spend sufficient time thinking about it.    You can also just look at $\Big \vert \det\big(a_i M V_i M^{-1}\big)\Big \vert = \Big \vert \det\big(U_i\big)\Big \vert = 1$ to conclude that if $V_i$ is unitary then $\vert a_i \vert =1$.

Comment: I disagree that you have answered it: I am asking if one can prove that $|a_i|=1$ given the two properties I stated in my previous comment. I agree with you that $|a_i|=1$ is equivalent to $V_i$ being unitary, but it is unclear how to prove either of these two (equivalent) properties from the properties (i) and (ii) in my previous message.